# display content of entity (table)

Tags: hibernate, jsf, entity

I have two entities

```
   @Entity    
    public class Tabulka{

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tabulka")
    private List<VysledkyHraca> vysledkyHraca;
.
.
.

}
```

and

```
    @Entity
    public class VysledkyHraca{

    @ManyToOne
        private Tabulka tabulka;
.
.
.

    }
```

now I create new instance of VysledkyHraca and save it in database:

```
em.merge(vysledkyHraca);
```

where em is EntityManager em;

but when I want to write Tabulka items

```
<h:dataTable value="#{item.vysledkyHraca}" var="item1" >
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="hrac"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item1.hrac}"/>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

I didnt see in this table new item. I have to build and run this aplication again to see this new item.  What I need to do if I wanna see this new item immediately ?

I try to call em.flush or em.refresh but it didnt help

thx for help

Comment: Is your problem in the page of JSF,or in the backing bean? Put a break point and see if in the backend the data is different than in the frontend

Comment: I use System.out.println() to write result of namedquery and here is the problem that record isnt up-to-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to manually update the entity in Tabulka add another methode:

```
public void addVysledkyHraca(VysledkyHraca v){
  this.vysledkyHraca.add(v);
  if(v.getTabulka()!=this)
      v.setTabulka(this); 

}
```

in VysledkyHraca:

```
 public void setTabulka(Tabulka t) {
    this.tabulka = t;
    if (!t.getVysledkyHraca().contains(this)) {
        t.getVysledkyHraca().add(this);
    }
}
```

when you're updating a tabulka just call addVysledkyHraca to add a new VysledkyHraca to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not updating existing data you need to use em.persist(newIstance);
If you want to  see  immediate changes you need to add some ajax abilities to your application for that i recommande you  Icefaces or Richfaces.

Comment: yes I am using em.persist and I see in database that new record was created. I think that problem can be in named query. When it is first called this namedquery it display right result but when it is called secondly, thirdly ... it didnt display up-to-date record when I using join in named query. My temporary solution is that manually updating this entity (when id is equal I add vysledky hraca to tabulka) and it work but I dont think that this is right solution.

Comment: or problem is in entity manager. I am using this: @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;